# Is there a way to configure JMS Serializer to ignore annotations?

Tags: php, joomla, jms-serializer

I'm using JMS Serializer in a Joomla! project but it seems there are several annotations that don't work properly with the library. I cannot remove those annotations because they are inside of Joomla! code so if the user updates the code, those annotations will be there again.

Is there a way to configure the serializer to ignore all the annotations?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think several annotations do not work with the library? Can you tell some specific observations, error messages or else?

Comment: @peter_the_oak My issue is mainly related with "note" annotation but I don't know if that annotation is a standard one.